# Restart uploading at another page by jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

We have a requirement to upload some files into the server during the process of a wizard. However, if the file upload fails at current step, the user is allowed to proceed to the next steps and restart file uploading at any stage of the wizard, without having to re-pick the files.

I understand it is of security reason that fileapi has disabled getting the address of the file and using the file address to initialize the file object. However, is it possible to use json to serialize that file object and store in Cookie/Session/Database and deserialize in the next pages?

If that's possible, will that also be a security issue? If not, is it possible to implement my scenario? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't matter what you store it as, you don't have access to the users filesystem, and the paths you'll get is `fakepath/filename`, and even if you could store the files, you can't set the value of a file input, so it can't be done.

Comment: The file upload in chrome will not give you the proper path, but if you are using IE you can get the filepath of the files to be uploaded. But I guess your application is not browser specific. Is there a size limit to the files being uploaded?